# Hi. How can I make this effect in ilustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

How can i make this effect in illustrator. Thank you in advanced

[image]

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. What have you tried? What has failed?

Comment: Its not a bad question. Though it does show a bit a lack of effort. But still its just that this has been asked before